# Mechanical roller animation

Tags: animation, physics

I am making animations with rollers that move cubes. Here is a video I already made. I animated the cubes by hand...

[link to youtube video](https://youtu.be/rhCppJ-nLH4)

I am wondering it is possible to use physics to automate the cubes. I tried using rigid body world and forces like wind but it didn't really work. Is there a way to do this/is there an add-on I should look into for doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using gravity? If you put gravity as z=10 (i.e. pushing upwards) and y=10 (pushing against back of stacker), then that would do the stacking. If you then animate the Physics/RigidBody/Settings/Dynamic toggle, you can turn gravity off for each object until the stacker reaches it.

You might want to use an invisible plane or two as passive rigid bodies to control the movement, as the stacker geometry is relatively complicated so might not work well as a collision object.